# gtest: check if string is equal to one of two strings

Tags: c++, googletest

Consider that I have two strings:

```
std::string s1 = "ab"; 
std::string s2 = "cd";
```

and I want to check (e.g. using EXPECT_EQ) if some given `std::string str` is equal either to `s1` or `s2`.

If gtest's `ASSERT_*` and `EXPECT_*` would return `bool` I could have written

```
EXPECT_TRUE(EXPECT_EQ(str, s1) || EXPECT_EQ(str, s2));
```

but, unfortunately, they don't.

Comment: What about assigning to bool variable and expect the variable value

Comment: `EXPECT_TRUE(str==s1 || str==s2)` ?

Comment: @ikanab OK, it will work, thanks. I just wanted to know if there is a gtest macro for such test.

Comment: Of course, you can write your own macro.

Comment: It's fortunate that they don't because your test would fail whenever `str` didn't equal `s1`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is one problem with `EXPECT_TRUE` in this case. In [gtest's doc](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/advanced.md#predicate-assertions-for-better-error-messages) it is described as:

> sometimes a user has to use EXPECT_TRUE() to check a complex
> expression, for lack of a better macro. This has the problem of not
> showing you the values of the parts of the expression, making it hard
> to understand what went wrong.

So it is suggested to use `EXPECT_PRED`:

```
TEST(CompareStr, Test1) {
  std::string s1 = "ab";
  std::string s2 = "cd";
  std::string str;
  EXPECT_PRED3([](auto str, auto s1, auto s2) {
    return str == s1 || str == s2;}, str, s1, s2);
}
```

It gives a bit better diagnostic if a unittest fails:

```
[ RUN      ] CompareStr.Test1
Test.cpp:5: Failure
[](auto str, auto s1, auto s2) { return str == s1 || str == s2;}(str, s1, s2) evaluates to false, where
str evaluates to 
s1 evaluates to ab
s2 evaluates to cd
```

You can compare the message above with the output from `EXPECT_TRUE`:

```
Value of: s1 == str || s2 == str
  Actual: false
Expected: true
```

Comment: Thanks for putting me into the right direction, but even so, your sample is **wrong**:

You have to use `EXPECT_PRED2` only with `s1` and `s2` of course.
Just try your sample with `s1 = "ab"` and `s2 = "ab"`. Test will fail since "str" is always an empty string!

Answer (score 9):

Try it:

```
std::string s1 = "ab";
std::string s2 = "cd";
std::string str = "ab";

EXPECT_TRUE(s1 == str || s2 == str);
```

Comment: I am in the situation that I have used as described and now I don't know why test is failing on server build but locally the tests succeeds. See bellow for a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ASSERT_STREQ` or `EXPECT_STREQ` instead of `EXPECT_EQ` for comparing strings. Therefore, you need to convert the `std::string` to a C string.

For your example:

```cpp
std::string s1 = "ab";
std::string s2 = "cd";
ASSERT_STREQ(s1.c_str(), s2.c_str());
```

Reference: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/reference/assertions.md